# When SQL isn't explicitly installed what is the default data store Visual Studio 2012 and/or Entity Framework 5/6?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

I have the situation below and can't figure out where everything is being saved.

I'm using a new installation of Visual Studio 2012 and didn't explicitly install any version of SQL.  I created a Console project in VS and used NuGet to add references to the latest -Pre version of EF (6.0.1 at the time).

When I did the database operations I wanted (just some test stuff: create, add, query, migrations, etc.) everything worked.  Shutdown the application, bring it back up and the data was persisted correctly.  No problem so far.

When I went to look at the database I was surprised to find that I didn't have Management Studio installed.  I also wasn't able to see any databases in the SQL Server Object Explorer in VS2012.  I could see a "(localdb)\Projects" server but my database wasn't in it.

When I checked the generated connection string it was:
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestProject.Context;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True

Using add server in the SQL Server Object Explorer I had to manually enter server names since none were found automatically.  I tried localhost\SQLEXPRESS, (localdb)\SQLSERVER, .\SQLEXPRESS, and other similar variants, but those couldn't be found either.

Where is everything being saved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If SqlExpress is not installed the default is `(localdb)\v11.0` which is installed when you install VS2012 (or VS2013).

Comment: OK.  That's still not view-able though.  Assuming that is where it's going why can't I see it in the Object Explorer?

Comment: Not sure why. You should be able to see it by adding a new connection in the Object Explorer (note that (localdb)\Projects is something different than (localdb)\v11.0). If you have an instance of DbContext you can always display the connection string the context is using - `ctx.Database.Connection.ConnectionString`.

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned that above, it's connecting to .\SQLEXPRESS in the connection string.  That's why it's so weird.  If that works for it (EF in general--I guess), why doesn't it work for the Object Explorer...

Comment: Maybe you have some additional options set in the dialog you use - like Sql Server authentication or TCP/IP as protocol? It basically seems that the options you provide in the dialog are different from the one that you use in the connection string.